# can someone help me idk which mean to 1 do

Tags: c

[image]

I tried to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h >

int main(void) {

    int common = 0;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int big;
    int small;
    int i; 
    printf("Enter the first number  : ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Enter the second  number  : ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    if (num1 <= num2) {
        num1 = small;
        num2 = big;
    }
    else{
        num1 = big;
        num2 = small; 
    }
    for  (i = small ; ; i++)
    {

    }
```

I don't know what is meant by to 1 do. I'm beginner in algorithms
but I think it means i++ isn't?

Comment: You need a condition in the `for()` loop to tell it whether to repeat or stop.

Comment: To elaborate on @Barmar's comment, a `for` loop will continue as long as the condition evaluates to true.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: On an unrelated sidenote: Under Windows you can use Snipping Tool to cut areas of the screen. With that you don't need to add screenshots of whole desktop while you only meed a small part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm says to count from `small` down to `1`. So the repetition should be `i--`, not `i++`. Use `i >= 1` as the repetition condition to keep looping until you get to `1`.

```
for (i = small; i >= 1; i--)
```